# J2ME: write on txt file or csv

Tags: java-me

I developp and app in J2ME.
I have some data in a txt file file called "access.txt"( a table with 2 columns and 10 lines). Every column contain integer. I can read the cells of the file.

Now my problem is :
I want to replace a specific cells by another integer by writng on the file programmatically.
How can i do it?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are aware of logic text file read/write operations in j2me
below are few things you need to figure out.

1) While creating text file you need row & column separation character.

e.g.

1*emp1#
2*emp2#
3*emp3#

in above example '*' is column separator whereas '#' is column separator.

2) In case of updating you need to read entire text file in string.
then simply parse it using basic string operations.

e.g. in above case if you need to update integer 2 with integer 4 
then read the first column until you get integer to be change.(remember you have row & column separators so that you can read them one by one.)

3) update the value 2 to 4.
4) Write (Do not appnend) entire string to the text file.

Comment: Thank you. About writing on the text file, i have a problem to define the path. I m developping with NetBean and I put my txt file in the "nbproject" folder. I can read it by using "this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)". But for writing i don't know how to define the path.

Comment: AFAIK you cant have write permission for the files which are in jar. Further you cannot write to internal storage of the device. External sd card is the only place where you can write the text file. there are several examples availble on web to write file on sd card. (You can move you text file from resource to external sd card then write contents on it.).